# Error when setting up Iphone device on visual studio xamarin hot restart

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: Error when setting up Iphone device on visual studio xamarin hot restart]

Error when setting up Iphone device on visual studio 2019 xamarin hot restart. my account is link to an organization with developers program active

Comment: You need to be an Admin

Comment: thank you I will check and post an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add permissions for the users in Appstore Connect > users & access. However, it means that these users will only receive access to App Store Connect and are not considered part of the team in the Apple Developer Program.

The best way is to login the AppleDeveloper Account in VS by the Account Holder's AppleId.

For more information, please refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=windows#new-wildcard-app-id.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1713/_index.html.